# HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode no definition for SelectNodes

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I am trying to use the HtmlAgilityPack to finds elements within a website.
My Problem is the following:

I created a Windows 8 universal app (c#)

With the NuGet Manager I added:

```
using System.Net.Http;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
```

Then i did:

```
string htmlPage;
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.domain.de/");
}

HtmlDocument myDocument = new HtmlDocument();
myDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);

//this line results an error @ "SelectNodes"
var metaTags = myDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//meta");
```

But visual studio says:

```
Error 1 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'SelectNodes'
```

I already googled the problem but all websites just solved another problem where the code said "DocumentElement" instead of "DocumentNode".

Do you have any hints?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `SelectNodes` is not available on WP8 but you can use;

```
var metaTags = myDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("meta");
```

instead.

Comment: Okay, but how do you do more complicated XPATH queries?

Comment: To do the equivalent of

doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@itemprop='softwareVersion']")

use

doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(p => p.GetAttributeValue("itemprop", "") == "softwareVersion")