# 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'SelectNodes'

Tags: c#, windows-phone, html-agility-pack, selectnodes

> 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' does not contain a definition for 'SelectNodes' and no extension method 'SelectNodes' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have setup config such as:

This is the code!!!

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string html = await client.GetStringAsync(Url);
        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
        var a =htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='verse']");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766242/htmlagilitypack-htmlnode-no-definition-for-selectnodes

Comment: What's the platform? Windows Phone,WinRT,WPF,ASP.NET,else?

Comment: windows phone silverlight 8.

Comment: @TaGiang check my answer

Answer (score 2):

HAP version for Windows Phone doesn't expose `SelectNodes()` method due to lack of XPath support available for WP. You need to resort to use HAP LINQ API to do the same :

```cs
var a = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
                    .Descendants("p")
                    .Where(p => p.GetAttributeValue("class","") == "verse");
```

Comment: go to file .dll right click => property=> unblock  just add sucess