# HTML Agility Pack SelectSingleNode method not listed on Universal Apps (C#)

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am developing a simple web scraping app in C# and here is my code to load html code received from the server to `HtmlDocument`.

```
string html = res.Content.ToString();
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
```

Whenever I try to use the `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode` method I am getting this error:

> "Html node does not contain a reference for SelectSingleNode".

Am I missing something?

I am developing a universal app in Visual Studio 2015. Downloaded and installed html agility pack using Nuget manager.

Comment: What's your XPath syntax? Provide complete code.

Comment: Leave the syntax.. I am not even getting the method to be displayed on intellisense.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766242/htmlagilitypack-htmlnode-no-definition-for-selectnodes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Universal app* doesn't support XPath. So you can not use *SelectSingleNode* or *SelectNodes* methods. But You can use Linq, like

```
    doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("a")
       .Where(a => a.InnerText.Contains("some text"))
       .Select(a => a.Attributes["href"].Value);
```

to get the same nodes

Comment: @SirwanAfifi  From question: `I am developing a universal app in Visual Studio 2015` I think it is clear. What do you think?