# REGEX the HREF information and count from matches

Tags: c#, html, regex

I'm trying to determine the number of `href` attributes in my C# script.
Below is the HTML I get back from my StreamReader and passed to a var (`responsefromserver`)

```html
<html>
<head><title>Index of /file-download/isin/20170917/</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<h1>Index of /file-download/isin/20170917/</h1><hr><pre><a 
href="../">../</a>
<a href="Commodities/">Commodities/</a>                                       
18-Sep-2017 00:05                   -
<a href="Credit/">Credit/</a>                                            
18-Sep-2017 00:05                   -
<a href="Equity/">Equity/</a>                                            
18-Sep-2017 00:05                   -
<a href="Foreign_Exchange/">Foreign_Exchange/</a>                                  
18-Sep-2017 00:05                   -
<a href="Rates/">Rates/</a>                                             
18-Sep-2017 00:05                   -
</pre><hr></body>
</html>
```

What I want to do is get a match (using regex) so I can count the number of `href` in the URL (these can vary from 1 - 5 max. (Commodities, Credit, Equity, FX & Rates) I can then pass the count to a variable to use later on.

The `href` names never change but I need to confirm the count so I can then check that the count of the files downloaded matches the count of the `href` (each `href` has a file beneath it).

My regex skills are rubbish and I can never match just on the terms (Commodities, Credit, Equity, FX & Rates) so any help building that string up would be great.

Any guidance would be great, I'm not a big C# user, I'm using this within a SSIS package, I have the use of the HTMLAgilityPack, so if there is another way that is cleaner/better than I am open to suggestion. Any code snippets that i can use, that give me what i need, using XPath would be handy as I'm not a regular c# user (yet)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all: **Don't use Regex to parse HTML** (you already mentioned HTML Agility Pack - use that and find what you need with XPath). What do you mean by *"so I can count the number of href in the URL"*?

Comment: I knew that would be the response! Ill take that one on the chin and start looking at Xpath. What I mean by Count is the URL can have anything from 1 attribute to 5 attributes, depending on the files being made available, I want to get a count of what is there

Comment: Excellent choice ;). I know Regex can be tempting, but this might be a classic example of "If you have a problem and try to solve it with Regex you end up with two problems".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to declare the strings you want to matches

```
string[] toMatch = {"Rates","Foreign_Exchange","Equity","Credit","Commodities"};
```

The Xpath for link with a href attribute is `"//a[@href]"`.
To know if a Href is in the list you want in to matches with you simply:

```
toMatch.Any(myHrefValue.Contains)
```

Resulting in the following code:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(input);
string[] toMatch = {"Rates","Foreign_Exchange","Equity","Credit","Commodities"};
var result = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
                .Select(tag => tag.Attributes["href"].Value)
                .Where(link => toMatch.Any(s => link.Contains(s)));
```

You now have all Href that matches. A simple `.Count()` is the last step you need.

Comment: Instead of `Where( ... Any( ) )` you could use the `Count` extension method directly

Comment: @thehennyy, Yeah just remplacing the `Where` with `Count` works but I did it that way for 2 reason: 1/. I find it more readable, and wanted to show Where clause. 2/. I did not want to give the expected result as sample code right away.

Comment: Wow, awesome thats really helpful. One thing im noticing, and this is kind of why i went back to Regex ( I know thats bad)... when i was trying similar code, i could never get "SelectNodes" to work. I get an error "Object does not contain a reference to SelectNodes....". I have a namespace for HTMLAgilityPack. but it will not build whilst SelectNodes is present, will i have to convert this to use Linq instead?

Comment: Can  you provide rue code caudsing rue error. Perhaps you re not calling it on the right object

Comment: the code is as above, a simple drag and drop into my code

Comment: @JayBay2279, on Windows phone by any chance? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27766242/htmlagilitypack-htmlnode-no-definition-for-selectnodes.

Comment: No, id read that was an issue, im using SSIS (So business Inteligence Project, writing C# scripts (as tasks) I supose this is a universal Script, and I have seen, although hadnt put 2+2 together that HTMLAgilityPack doesnt fully work in universal app.

Comment: You can use `.Descendants("a")` instead of `.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")` as I was just showing how to access `a` with a `href` property. But there is no need of that because you gonna check those who match right after.

Comment: I get that same error with Decendants as well,,, Grr

Comment: Decendants should be working. I thinks it's an other question make you sure add every information about what type of project, what are the lib used, the application information from project properties. When there is no xpath decendants should work. Make a little [mcve].

Comment: @JayBay2279 wait! Is `.Descendants()` Working? with no argument in it

Answer (score 0):

Working with regex as SSIS seems to be limiting.
you should use a pattern like this : `href="(Commodities|Credit|Equity|Foreign_Exchange|Rates)\/"`.

```
string pattern = @"href=""(Commodities|Credit|Equity|Foreign_Exchange|Rates)\/""";
var result = Regex.Matches(input, pattern).Count;
```

If you need to build up pattern from db:

```
string[] toMatch = { "Rates", "Foreign_Exchange", "Equity", "Credit", "Commodities" };
string pattern2  = @"href=""("+String.Join("|", toMatch)+@")\/""";
```

The issue is if you have no control over the Html input. As this will match Any Href not only the link. a regex like this : `<a.*href="(Commodities|Credit|Equity|Foreign_Exchange|Rates)\/"`